# DropDownListFor gives error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to have a dropdown in my view, but that dropdown should have categories loaded from database.

I am using Entity Framework Code First Approach in MVC 5.

Here is my **Model**:

```
public class CreateProductModel
{
   
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public SelectList Categories { get; set; } 

        [MaxLength]
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

    
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ProductModel();
    model.CreateProductModel.Categories = new SelectList(_db.Categories, "CategoryID", "Name", 1);
    return View(model);
}
```

**View:**

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateProductModel.CategoryID, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CreateProductModel.CategoryID, new SelectList(Model.CreateProductModel.Categories, "CategoryID", "Name", 1), "Please Select Category");
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Because the `CreateProductModel` property of `ProductModel` is null (you need to initialize that first - `model.CreateProductModel = new CreateProductModel();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize `CreateProductModel` property:

```
var model = new ProductModel();
model.CreateProductModel = new CreateProductModel();
model.CreateProductModel.Categories = new SelectList(_db.Categories, "CategoryID", "Name", 1);
```

Comment: Many Thanks. You are awesome.. Its Working :)

Comment: At that time it was showing 7 minutes wait to accept answer :)